# Make nginx load different locations for PC and mobile devices

Tags: nginx

I'd like to make PC and mobile devices load different index's files.

So, before the nginx main "location", I tried creating an "if" like this:

```
# START MOBILE
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
    location / {
        try_files /my/dir/here/index-mobile.html $uri $uri/ /index.php ;
    }    
}
```

However, I get "nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here". As location isn't allowed inside an if, what are the directions in order to achieve nginx serving different files for different conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as indicated: the `location` directive is not allowed inside an `if`.  There are actually only a few things that are safe to do within `if` directives, examples are `rewrite` and `return`.  See the documentation for more detailed [information](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).  Something the documentation doesn't mention is that under certain conditions `set` is also safe to use.

In your specific case, try something like this:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* android) {
    rewrite ^ /mobile/$request_uri last; # internal rewrite
}

location /mobile {
}
```

Note that I haven't verified your regular expression.  I am sure you can tweak that according to your needs.

Comment: Should it be `rewrite .* /mobile/$request_uri last;`?

Comment: @calfzhou Thank you for spotting that minor error. Your solution would work, but consider using `rewrite ^ /mobile/$request_uri last;` instead. The simple `^` pattern is much cheaper to match than `.*` is.